Missing Log Events When Multiple instance of application writing to same log file log4j2
our standalone (not web) application spans into multiple instances in single VM , which is writing logs into same json log file( reason not using different logs as we need to shipping these logs to Lumberjack).  Due to this some events are missing as one process overwrites other process logs. is there special appender we can use to solve this problem or we have to write our own appender. (not have option to use SocketAppender)
SocketAppender is not an option.
